# Correct use of the context module to overtake the blocks assignments page?

Tags: blocks, 7

Currently I'm using the regular blocks page to make assignments to the head/footer regions as those are relatively static. But one issue im running into is that I need to assign the "main content" block into a region or else I can't save the block page.

This poses a problem as I'm also using the context module to make block assignments such as view blocks in the content area. Since the "main content" block is assigned in the regular blocks page, I can't get context to place blocks above the main content block.

- Is there a way to just just context entirely over the blocks page?
- How do you resolve the "main content" blocks being as a required block assignment on the blocks page?